# excel formula or vba to enumerate duplicate values from one column into another

Tags: excel, duplicates, formula, enumeration

I have 2 columns, A and B. 'Column B' has a numeric value.
I need 'column A' to enumerate the number of times each number is repeated in 'column B', without summing them.

```
A   B
1  0001
2  0001
3  0001
1  0011
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data starts in row 1 with no headers, put this in cell A1 and drag/copy down:
`=COUNTIF(B$1:B1,B1)`

Comment: Its returning a sum of duplicated values, I need duplicated value to be enumerated ascendantly.  Your formula is returning the sum each value is repeated.

Comment: @AndréDias Enumerate literally means 'to count' which is what this formula is doing. It may look like its summing based on the first 3 values since they're 1. Is the sample data you've placed in your question representative of the expected behaviour (ie. the results in column A what you _want_ to see)?

Comment: correct, I am looking to have in Column A the count of the times each value in column B is duplicated. So if column B has 3 rows with a numeric value, lets say 100, in Column A the rows will show 1,2,3.

Comment: Okay, that's what this formula does. If this is not the solution you're looking for I recommend clarifying your question.